# How do you wrap large images to a 3D Body model to make large tattoos that span from different parts of the body (back to arms to legs etc)

Tags: texturing, image, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I've been looking around at tutorials to use stencils for tattoos on body models and so on but I find if say, have a design of a koi and I want it to span a large portion of the back, leading down to a leg and ending on the inner thigh, I get the feeling that stopping to rotate the model manually and then re-sizing and aligning the stencil to match up with the previously applied stencil isn't the best way to go about such a task. Is there any way to fully wrap a model with a picture?

*Eg.

define the path the image should be wrapped along on the model and then clean and finish in the texture editor or Photoshop.*

^^^^
Is something like that possible?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Did you try UV unwrap and export the UV to photoshop?

Comment: I would recommend using the Bake function to bake an image that is imported as a plane and highly subdivided and snapped of the surface faces of the intended target. Possibly bake to a separate image that can be adjusted to be transparent where the tattoo is not.

Comment: @Emir -  Thanks for the suggestion but, I understand that method but what i was trying to do was apply a large image of the mesh of a character body which has UV sector of varying size so cutting and resizing then ensuring that they all line up in photoshop seems to be even more difficult than what im doing right now.

Comment: @CraigDJones - Ok, new to blender but i'll look up those functions and give it a shot. thanks